# jquery, why id selector doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery

On the start page, i need hide a div dlaFirmy.
this notation $('#dlaFirmy').hide(); does not work. If i use $('table').hide(); 
and it can easily hide.

Probably above statement is incorrect.
Thank you in advance for your help

```
javascript code:
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){     
    $('#dlaFirmy').hide();
    $('select').on('change', function (e) {
       var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
       var valueSelected  = optionSelected.val();
       if( valueSelected === "2"){
           $('#dlaFirmy').show();
            alert("sdfsd");
       }
       else {
           $('#dlaFirmy').hide();
       }

       });
       });

Html code :

    <div class="formularzOC">
        <form id="form1" action="dodajDistrictManager.do" method="POST">
                <div id="podmianka"> <b>Dodaj nowy Lead: </b></div>

        <table>
            <select name="thelist">
                <option value="1">Klient Indywidualny</option>
                <option value="2">Klient Biznesowy</option>
            </select> 
            <tr>
                <td>Imię:</td><td><input type="text" name="imie" ></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Nazwisko:</td><td><input type="text" name="nazwisko" ></td>
            </tr>
            ...

           <div id="dlaFirmy"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>Nazwa firmy:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" ></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nip:</td><td><input type="text" name="email" ></td>
                </tr>
           </div>

        </table>
            <button type="submit"> Zatwierdź</button>
    </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: It is invalid HTML to encase `<tr>`'s with a `<div>`. The browser might not be registering it.

Comment: Working here: http://jsfiddle.net/v3zn6mge/ ==> apart from markup is corrupt

Comment: ok, i sloved a problem. I deleted a div from table, and then for the next two tr, gave class "usun" and i call function $('.usun').hide(). Thx for all for help.

Answer (score 3):

Your markup is wildly invalid, you can't rely on anything that the browser actually does.

[`table`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-table-element) elements cannot directly contain [`select`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element%C2%A3) elements or [`div`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) elements. If you put them inside a `table`, the browser is likely to move them outside of it.

`div` elements cannot directly contain [`tr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html#the-tr-element) elements.

Bottom line: You have to make your markup valid. For what you're trying to do, `tbody` rather than `div` (for `#dlaFirmy`) might make sense.

Answer (score 0):

In one case you are hiding a table, and in the other you are hiding a div. This is why you get different results.